# .NET UDP & DTLS

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, ssl, sslstream

Is there a native way to provide DTLS support for UDP sockets in .NET?

**edit** by native I mean those that are in .NET framework out-of-the-box.

Comment: Please define what you mean by "native".

Comment: Sorry, my English is not native :)

Answer (score -2):

Our SecureBlackbox product provides [client-side and server-side components for DTLS](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-ssl.php).

Comment: Thanks, Eugene. I know it. That's why I asked for native ways.

Comment: Another reason to ask is that I would pretty much enjoy the kind of interface SslStream offers.

Comment: I doubt that you will find anything - DTLS is quite specific and not very popular thing. Also, SslStream is a stream class, and turning UDP (DTLS-secured or not) into stream is a layer adds certain business logic, it's not just replace an interface and you are done.

Comment: Yes, I understand this. By interface I meant being able to layer encryption on top of any kind of stream. Such underlying stream could "consist" of encrypted packets sent via UDP from a certain endpoint.

Comment: Actually, this is something i could use as well. Does the C# implementation of SSLStream use UDP or TCP 'under the hood'? Does anyone know if there is an alternative FULLY-MANAGED udp tunnelling library?

Comment: @nterry asking unrelated questions in comments is a bad idea for StackOverflow - this is not a forum and nobody will see your questions in the comment to some old topic. You are welcome to post questions as, emm, new questions here, and get answers that way.